# ¿Se dice "a través de la medida de la deformación" o "a través de la medición de la deformación"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras

Al redactar un texto ¿es válida la expresión "a través de la medida de la deformación"? ¿O es mejor decir "a través de la medición de la deformación"?

Comment: ¿Nos das el contexto, por favor, y explicas un poco la idea?

Comment: Claro, se quiere escribir un texto de Ingeniería, se está hablando sobre un método que permite calcular las fuerzas que se ejercen sobre un elemento estructural mediante cierto dispositivo que mide las deformaciones en el elemento, entonces hay un párrafo que se quiere concluir con una de las dos afirmaciones anteriores, pero no me queda claro que diferencia haya entre ellas.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que la pregunta es realmente si hay alguna diferencia entre *[medida](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OlAN0dp)* y *[medición](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Ol2wI6X)*. Tal y como recoge el diccionario, ambas significan "acción y efecto de medir", por lo que en principio ambas opciones son válidas. El problema puede venir por el hecho de que *medida* también puede significar el "resultado de una medición", mientras que la propia palabra *medición* carece de esta ambigüedad.

Por tanto, yo aconsejaría decir "la medición de la deformación" para evitar la ambigüedad, y reservar la palabra "medida" para referirte a los resultados de las mediciones: "tras la medición de la deformación hemos obtenido una medida de 3 milímetros".